# I want use “isinstance” to judge what type object people input from keyboard

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code

```
num = input()
if  not isinstance(num,int):
    print("wrong input")
    num = input()
```

However if I type letters from keyboard,the computer gives this error：

```
please input a num
q
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ex11.py", line 8, in <module>
  num = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'q' is not defined
```

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I use the Python 2.7.6

Comment: Thank for your help,I think the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python2, `input` immediately tries to `eval` the input. You should use `raw_input` to get a string. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

It would also be more pythonic just to try to convert the user input to whatever format you need and handle exceptions that might occur:

```
inp = raw_input("enter a number:")
try:
  a = int(inp)
except ValueError:
  print "Could not convert input to int"
```